# Bitwise OR on security protocols

Tags: c#, .net, security, tls1.2

I've come across this in one of the .NET apps we use and was wondering what it actually does.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

I know that the `|=` operator is a shortcut for `x = x | y`, but that is a bitwise operator.

What does it do in relation to security protocols?

Comment: It's still a bitwise operator. Enums are just ints at their root. Using | and & with enums works the exact same way as using them with ints. You just have to be careful to give your enum options appropriate (e.g. power of 2) values.

Comment: This operator has nothing to do with Security protocols since it's just a setting of a flag. Can be done on any Enum (or maybe just flags enum).

Comment: You are adding (thus, enabling) the Tls1.2 protocol to the current `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` configuration. If it's added to the base configuration (`SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault` = 0), this means that only Tls1.2 will be enabled. `SystemDefault` means (usually, without any Registry modifications) Ssl 3.0 and Tls 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` property is a property of the [SecurityProtocolType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.securityprotocoltype(v=vs.110).aspx) enum type.

`System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` is one of the available flags on the SecurityProtocolType enum.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Is setting the flag for `Tls12` on `ServicePointManager`'s `SecurityProtocol` property.

The [SecurityProtocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation has these remarks about the property,

> This property selects the version of the Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) or Transport Layer Security (TLS) protocol to use for new connections that use the Secure Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTPS) scheme only; existing connections are not changed.

You can read more about the [FlagsAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to learn more about how bitwise operators can interact with `enum`s, with the gist of it being

> Bit fields are generally used for lists of elements that might occur in combination, whereas enumeration constants are generally used for lists of mutually exclusive elements. Therefore, bit fields are designed to be combined with a bitwise OR operation to generate unnamed values, whereas enumerated constants are not. Languages vary in their use of bit fields compared to enumeration constants.